CDK API Gateway Metrics are not shown
I'm newbie in AWS CDK world. I'm trying to enable metrics for an API Gateway so I've done the following when creating my API (specially for deploy_options that is supposed to do the metrics stuff)
api = aws_apigateway.RestApi(
    stack,
    id_,
    rest_api_name=name,
    description=description,
    endpoint_configuration=aws_apigateway.EndpointConfiguration(
        types=[aws_apigateway.EndpointType.PRIVATE], vpc_endpoints=[vpce]
    ),
    policy=my_policy_document,
    deploy_options=aws_apigateway.StageOptions(
        metrics_enabled=True,
        logging_level=aws_apigateway.MethodLoggingLevel.INFO,
        data_trace_enabled=True,
        tracing_enabled=True,  # Enable X-Ray tracing
    ),
)

# Retrieve and output various metrics
error_4xx_metric = api.metric_client_error()
error_5xx_metric = api.metric_server_error()
latency_metric = api.metric_latency()
request_count_metric = api.metric_count()

core.CfnOutput(stack, f"{id_}4xxErrorMetric", value=error_4xx_metric.metric_name)
core.CfnOutput(stack, f"{id_}5xxErrorMetric", value=error_5xx_metric.metric_name)
core.CfnOutput(stack, f"{id_}LatencyMetric", value=latency_metric.metric_name)
core.CfnOutput(
    stack, f"{id_}RequestCountMetric", value=request_count_metric.metric_name
)

I can see the expected outputs in the CloudFormation but then when I try to check them in my API Gateway Dashboard (or even in CloudWatch Metrics) I can't see any metric at all. This is driving me crazy and spent most part of the day trying to make this work.
PS: Logs & Tracing under API Gateway > Stages are enabled:

What I am missing?

Have there been any requests to the API?
